# VisualStateManager added via code behind does not triggered Windows 10

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile, visualstatemanager

I have a button created dynamically via code behind. The reason is because I want the `EntranceThemeTransition` repeat each time the button is visible.

```
<Grid x:Name="gridRoot">
    <Grid x:Name="gridNextKitty"  Visibility="{Binding IsNextKittyButtonVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
        <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <EntranceThemeTransition FromHorizontalOffset="1000" FromVerticalOffset="0" IsStaggeringEnabled="False"/>
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
        <!--<Button x:Name="btnNextKitty" Content="Next Kitty" FontSize="40" Command="{Binding BtnNextKittyClick}" Style="{StaticResource ButtonMenuStyle}" Background="#74b025" Width="300" Height="80" Margin="24" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>-->
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

The button is added like this

```
            if (viewModel.IsNextKittyButtonVisible)
            {
                btnNextKitty = new Button()
                {
                    Content = "Next Kitty",
                    FontSize = 40,
                    Command = viewModel.BtnNextKittyClick,
                    Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["ButtonMenuStyle"],
                    Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 116, 176, 37)),
                    Width = 300,
                    Height = 80,
                    Margin = new Thickness(24),
                    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center
                };

                gridNextKitty.Children.Add(btnNextKitty);
                addVisualStateManager();

            }
            else
            {
                gridNextKitty.Children.Remove(btnNextKitty);
                VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(gridRoot).Remove(vsg);
            }
```

I added the`VisualStateManager` via code behind but the `StateTriggers` is always true even though `MinWindowWidth` < 500.

```
    private void addVisualStateManager()
    {
        vsg = new VisualStateGroup();
        VisualState vs = new VisualState();
        vs.StateTriggers.Add(new AdaptiveTrigger
        {
            MinWindowWidth = 500,                
        });

        vs.Setters.Add(new Setter
        {
            Target = new TargetPropertyPath
            {
                Path = new PropertyPath("(FrameworkElement.Width)"),
                Target = btnNextKitty
            },

            Value = "240"
        });

        vsg.States.Add(vs);
        VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(gridRoot).Add(vsg);
    }
```

How do I make the trigger work via code behind?

Answer (score 0):

You should to add default state for width from 0 to 500.
For example, empty visual state.

```
vsg.States.Add(vs);

vs = new VisualState();
vs.StateTriggers.Add(new AdaptiveTrigger
{
    MinWindowWidth = 0,
});

vsg.States.Add(vs);
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion. The Button width only adjusted on the first entrance. Once the button removed and readded the trigger no longer work.

Answer (score 0):

I've chosen a different route. Instead of using `EntranceThemeTransition` I've decided to use `Storyboard` animation.

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="storyboardbtnNextKitty">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="btnNextKitty" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" From="1000" To="0"  Duration="0:0:0.5">
            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
        </DoubleAnimation>
    </Storyboard>
</Grid.Resources>
```

In the code behind, I subscribed to the `ViewModel_PropertyChanged` event. When `IsNextKittyButtonVisible` is true, I just play the animation.

```
if (viewModel.IsNextKittyButtonVisible)
{
    storyboardbtnNextKitty.Begin();
}
```

The button is created in XAML and not code behind.